# Using a Vertex Buffer in two different Vertex Array Objects

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

This is a theoretical question, so I don't have code until now.

Assuming that I have a VBO with vertex position data and am using it within a VAO to render an indexed (glDrawElements()) figure out of triangles with a special index array.

Now I want to reuse this data buffer within a second VAO to render some other figures consisting out of lines, but with a different index array.

How do I need to bind the buffers, so that I can reuse the vertex data of the first VAO?

Comment: Idk why, but to me it makes more sense to me to create multiple element arrays and change them than multiple vao's.

Comment: It seems to me a bit more modular, but I will think again about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

no special code is needed to share the buffers between VAOs just bind them as you normally would.

setting up:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, locBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, triangleBuffer);
glVertexAttrPointer(...);

glBindVertexArray(VAO[1]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, locBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, lineBuffer);
glVertexAttrPointer(...);
```

and when drawing:

```
glBindVertexArray(VAO[0]);
glDrawElements(...);

glBindVertexArray(VAO[1]);
glDrawElements(...);
```

Comment: To streamline it further, you can bind the ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER in the setup as well. That binding is part of the VAO state. Then you only need the `glBindVertexArray()` call before drawing.

Comment: @RetoKoradi wasn't sure about that, the docs are quite ambiguous about that.

Comment: I think it's running now. I will test it further and inform you. Thanks.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: It's not extensively documented. One conclusive data point is table 6.5 in the OpenGL 3.3 spec. The table is labeled "Vertex Array **Object** State", and contains `ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`. This contrasts with table 6.6, labeled "Vertex Array Data (**not in Vertex Array objects**)", which contains `ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING`.